# Grabbing from defined number of users using php mysql

Tags: php, sql

I'm try to grab data on a certain amount of users in game and I was hoping this would work:

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid='7906' TO '8055'";
```

I only want to grab data from userid 7906 up to userid 8055. How can I do this?

Comment: You're looking for [BETWEEN ... AND ...](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BETWEEN` Operator:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid BETWEEN 7906 AND 8055";
```

Comment: Both solutions worked

Answer (score 0):

You can check with operator as well:

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid >='7906' AND userid <= '8055'";
```